# Assembly Language (Order Taker)

Tags: arrays, assembly, storage, inventory

I'm trying hard to study Assembly language.

I really need help to store different 10 items in an array

I want to build a program that will accept items from 10 choices and it will store it.

Those 10 items have different value.

Example
Item 1 = 10$
Item 2 = 4$

So that when the User tries to choose Item1 and Item2 it will show the 
sum of both items.

I'll be gladly be happy if someone can share his/her own code that can store 10 items with the sum of all items. Thanks

Here's my code:

```
_start: 

   mov  eax,3      ;number bytes to be summed 
   mov  ebx,0      ;EBX will store the sum
   mov  ecx, x     ;ECX will point to the current element to be summed

top:  add  ebx, [ecx]

   add  ecx,1      ;move pointer to next element
   dec  eax        ;decrement counter
   jnz  top        ;if counter not 0, then loop again

done: 

   add   ebx, '0'
   mov  [sum], ebx ;done, store result in "sum"

display:

   mov  edx,1      ;message length
   mov  ecx, sum   ;message to write
   mov  ebx, 1     ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax, 4     ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80       ;call kernel

   mov  eax, 1     ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80       ;call kernel

section .data
global x
x:    
   db  2
   db  4
   db  3

sum: 
   db  0
```

My code here does have problem.

Comment: _"My code here does have problem."_ And that problem is...?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> x:    
> db  2
> db  4
> db  3
> sum: 
> db  0
> ```

Since you've defined all of your variables to be of **byte** type, you must process them as bytes! You're reading and writing **dwords** in your program.

This could have been OK:

```
top:  add  bl, [ecx]
      add  ecx, 1     ;move pointer to next element
      dec  eax        ;decrement counter
      jnz  top        ;if counter not 0, then loop again
done: 
      add  bl, '0'
      mov  [sum], bl  ;done, store result in "sum"
```